# How to solve this deck problem?

Tags: probability

*What is the probability of drawing a seven or a heart from a deck of 52 cards?*

I know that the answer is 4/13 and that (7 or Hearts) = P (7) + P (Hearts) - P (7 and Hearts) =  4/52 + 13/52 - P (7 and Hearts).

However, I am not sure what fraction to plug in for **P (7 and Hearts)** to reach the find answer of 4/13. Would P (7 and Hearts) = 17/52?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can add and subtract probability just like we do in sets.

Probability = (P of drawing 7) + (P of drawing hearts) - (P of drawing 7 and hearts)
$$P= {4\over 52}+{13\over 52}-{1\over 52}$$
$$P= {16\over 52} = {4\over 13}$$

Answer (score 4):

P(7 and Hearts) is just 1/52 because the only card that meets that case is the seven of Hearts.

Comment: I see. Thanks for clearing that up! :)

Answer (score 1):

We have

- $4$ seven and others $12$ hearts (one of the $7$'s is heart)

therefore

$$p=\frac{16}{52}=\frac4{13}$$